# How to pass additional parameter with dynamic routes in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Reactjs and using nextjs,My [slug.js] is working fine with following url

```
<Link href={`/${post.slug}`}><a>
```

But i want to send/pass "hidden"(additional parameter) with this,whenever i try to do then i am getting 404 error,I want this because in some page i want to use different api in "serversideprops",Right now here is my code

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
    console.log(params); // right now i am getting "slug" as parameter
    if(params.anotherparamter)
    {
        //futher code
    }
    elseif(params.slug){    
        const { data: data2 } = await Axios.get(`https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${params.slug}`);
    }
    const blogs = data2;
    return {
        props: {
           blogs: blogs
        },
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` prop to hide the query string.

Your link would look something like this

```
<Link href={`/${post.slug}?myparam="mysecret"`} as={`/${post.slug}`}></Link> //The link will not show the query param when redirected
```

You will then be able to access the `myparam` query in your serverSideProps like so.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params, query }) => {
...
const { myparam } = query
console.log(myparam) // will return mysecret as a string
```

You can read more from the docs